# PHP / Python script that base64encodes images in css

Tags: php, python, css, base64

I find myself manually encoding background images in the css in base64 often.

When I mean manually, I mean that I encode the image, copy the resulting string, paste it into the css file and so on. This is stupid!

I came to the conclusion that writing a script in PHP or Python that does it automatically would not be difficult, it's just a matter of parsing the css, finding the image on the HD, encoding it in base64, replace the result with the original string in the css file and save a new file.

Then I thought: "how come nobody has already done this? Maybe it would be better to ask before doing it."

So here I am, does a similar solution exist?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well, **[Chris Coyer @ CSS-Tricks published an article talking about Data URIs](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)**, where he explains how to use them and how they are useful. Near the end, he states that's it's very easy to generate those on the fly with PHP, like so

> - if you are using PHP (or PHP as CSS), you could create data URIs on the fly like this
>
>   ```
>   <?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("../images/folder16.gif")) ?>
>   ```

However, take not that you shouldn't use `base64_encode` on **all** images on a website. the size of the string generated by `base64_encode` is larger by about 33% of the original image. Data URIs are great when you have small pictures and you don't want to waste requests on them.

Comment: pheraphs you didn't read well my question. I obviously know that function, I was wondering if there is a script available that parses a CSS file in input and automatically encodes the images in base64 and replace the string with the encoded file and finally save a new output file.

Comment: I read your question.  Whatyou're seeking is probably the wrong way. You shouldn't do it on every image.

Comment: you're missing the point entirely, I could easily introduce some code that makes me able to decide if and which images or files to exclude from the encoding, I did not ask if encoding images in the css is good or not, I asked if there's a script that parses the CSS and does it automatically!!